# Nginx: rewrite file from directory to root

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

I have nginx server running over linux environment, and it is handling the domains `www.example1.com` and `www.example2.com`. each domain has its own sitemap, so I need the correct sitemap loaded for each domain as it is in the root directory, for example:

`www.example1.com/sitemap.xml` is actually loaded from `www.example1.com/sitemaps/1/sitemap.xml`

And:

`www.example2.com/sitemap.xml` is actually loaded from `www.example2.com/sitemaps/2/sitemap.xml`

To achieve this, I've tried to assign a value for each domain and rewrite it based on the variable value like following:

in nginx.conf:

```
map $http_host $domain {
    www.example1.com      1;
    www.example2.com      2;
}
```

And in sitemap.conf:

```
if($domain=1){
  rewrite sitemaps/1/sitemap(.*)$ /sitemap last;
}
if($domain=2){
  rewrite sitemaps/2/sitemap(.*)$ /sitemap last;
}
```

But for some reason this configuration is returning 404.

Any advise?

Comment: `sitemap.conf` could be simplified like `rewrite sitemaps/$domain/sitemap(.*)$ /sitemap last;`. This doesn't prevent 404, though. 404 was likely due to other reasons (than the snippets shared in OP). Kindly share the full configuration to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your full config and don't know, how and where do you include that `sitemap.conf` file, but I'd rather did it in a complete different way. With your existing `map` block it would look like

```
location = /sitemap.xml {
    # use '$domain' variable as a part of the full path to 'sitemap.xml' file
    root /var/www/domain/sitemaps/$domain; # no trailing slash here!
}
```

or even get the full path to `/sitemaps/N/` folder with the `map` directive like

```
map $http_host $sitemap_path {
    www.example1.com      /var/www/example1.com/sitemaps/1;
    www.example2.com      /var/www/example1.com/sitemaps/2;
}
```

and

```
location = /sitemap.xml {
    # use '$sitemap_path' variable as the full path to 'sitemap.xml' file
    root $sitemap_path; # no trailing slash here!
}
```

If you still want to use the `rewrite` directive for this task, you are using it incorrectly. You can try this one:

```
if ($domain=1) {
    rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemaps/1/sitemap.xml last;
}
if ($domain=2) {
    rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemaps/2/sitemap.xml last;
}
```

or even more optimized:

```
if ($domain) {
    rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemaps/$domain/sitemap.xml last;
}
```

Comment: Full configs will be confusing, that's why I've added only the related part of the configuration.

Comment: Changing the root dir for the sitemap.xml location worked for me. For the rewrite part, what is the "last" is used for?

Comment: You can consider it as copy-paste from your original config. Generally, `last` flag does mean the whole URI procession should take place again, but this time for the altered `$uri` value.